# PostgreSQL Nested Loop Join Performance

Tags: postgresql, join, indexing, query-optimization

I have two tables `exchange_rate` (100 Thousand Rows) and `paid_date_t` (9 million rows) with below structure.

```
                           "exchange_rate"
           Column            |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-----------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 valid_from                  | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 valid_until                 | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 currency                    | text                     |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "exchange_rate_unique_valid_from_currency_key" UNIQUE, btree (valid_from, currency)
    "exchange_rate_valid_from_gist_idx" gist (valid_from)
    "exchange_rate_valid_from_until_currency_gist_idx" gist (valid_from, valid_until, currency)
    "exchange_rate_valid_from_until_gist_idx" gist (valid_from, valid_until)
    "exchange_rate_valid_until_gist_idx" gist (valid_until)
```

```
                       "paid_date_t"
      Column       |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 currency          | character varying(3)        |           |          | 
 paid_date         | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 

Indexes:
    "paid_date_t_paid_date_idx" btree (paid_date)
```

I am running below select query and joining these tables based on multiple join keys:

```
SELECT
 paid_date
FROM     exchange_rate erd
       JOIN paid_date_t sspd
             ON sspd.paid_date >= erd.valid_from AND sspd.paid_date < erd.valid_until
                 AND erd.currency = sspd.currency
WHERE sspd.currency != 'USD'
```

However, the performance of the query is inefficient and takes hours to execute. The query plan below shows that it using a nested loop join.

```
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.28..44498192.71 rows=701389198 width=40)
   ->  Seq Scan on paid_date_t sspd  (cost=0.00..183612.84 rows=2557615 width=24)
         Filter: ((currency)::text <> 'USD'::text)
   ->  Index Scan using exchange_rate_valid_from_until_currency_gist_idx on exchange_rate erd  (cost=0.28..16.53 rows=80 width=36)
         Index Cond: (currency = (sspd.currency)::text)
         Filter: ((sspd.paid_date >= valid_from) AND (sspd.paid_date < valid_until))
```

I have worked with different indexing methods but got the same result. I know that `<=` and `>=` operators are not supporting merge or hash joins.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: As pointed out below, the only index you want on `exchange_rate` is a simple `btree` with the fields `currency, valid_from, valid_until` (in that order! The index may or may not be unique, it doesn't matter as you won't be able to ensure non-overlap this way anyway so why bother?). That said, I'm having a hard time understanding how that table can have 100k rows. There are only 180 currencies and I'm confident you don't use all of them. How do you make this explode to 100k rows? Does it store this day by day? Wouldn't it make sense to put some effort in merging consecutive ranges? (edit: typo)

Comment: Afterthought: BECAUSE you can't guarantee non-overlap between the records in `exchange_rate` you may want to use a `WHERE EXISTS()` rather than a `JOIN` in the query. E.g. if you have a record that is valid from day A to day G and another one for the same currency that is valid from day E to day Q then the construction as is will return paid_date F twice. Also, you may want to get rid of all the other indexes once you found the one that works for your requirements, non-used indexes bring overhead in INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operations, will eat extra disk (and cache!) and confuse the optimizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a smaller table with just a sample of the rows from paid_date_t in it.  It is hard to optimize a query if it takes a very long time each time you try to test it.

Your btree index has the column tested for equality as the 2nd column, which is certainly less efficient.  The better btree index for this query (as it is currently written) would be something like `(currency, valid_from, valid_until)`.

For a gist index, you really want it to be on the time range, not on the separate end points of the range.  You could either convert the table to hold a range type, or build a functional index to convert them on the fly (and then rewrite the query to use the same expression).  This is complicated by the fact that your tables have different types due to the different handling of time zones.  The index would look like:

```
create index on exchange_rate using gist (tstzrange(valid_from,valid_until), currency);
```

and then the ON condition would look like:

```
ON sspd.paid_date::timestamptz <@ tstzrange(erd.valid_from, erd.valid_until)
             AND erd.currency = sspd.currency
```

It might be faster to have the order of the columns in the gist index be reversed from what I show, you should try it both ways on your own data and see.

Comment: I have checked this and yes it does improve performance a lot, however I am not sure and don't know if the created tstzrange is the same range as I have in my ON clause of the query which is ```sspd.paid_date >= erd.valid_from AND sspd.paid_date < erd.valid_until``` or is it ```sspd.paid_date >= erd.valid_from AND sspd.paid_date <= erd.valid_until```

Comment: A good thing to double check!  The tstzrange will include the exact start point and exclude the exact endpoint.  If you wanted it to include both endpoints, you would give tstzrange a third argument of `'[]'`.